# How to use visual studio code create auto lisp in Autocad 2021

Tags: autolisp

My auto cad 2021 can't create auto lisp with visual lisp editor, but will be created by visual studio code.
How to create auto lisp with visual studio code. or please share link create auto lisp with visual studio code.
thank you for all comment.

Comment: You can opt to continue to use the VL IDE by setting LISPSYS=0